# My Springboot Application works fine on my Local Server but returns 404 when hosted to my DailyRazor Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, hosting

I am trying to host my springboot hibernate application to my tomcat server on DailyRazor but I am encountering an issue. After creating a deployable War file and dropping it in the webapps folder directly, I still receive a 404 page when when trying to access my website. All apis return this 404 page even the root api.

I have been trying to solve this for a few weeks now and I have seen all the common mistakes and I believe that I have configured my springboot application correctly. I have overrided the configure method and I have made sure to extend the SpringBootServletInitializer, but the problem still persists. Since I am creating my project in Intellij, I am generating the war file by using the gradlew bootWar in the CMD.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Run extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryCreator.createSessionFactory();


   public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Run.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Run.class);
    }


}
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.teamtreehouse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'



allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    group = 'com.wnp'
    version = '6.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.spring.dependency-management/io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin
    implementation 'io.spring.dependency-management:io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin:1.1.0'

//    'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.2.2.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.maven.plugins', name: 'maven-surefire-plugin', version: '2.22.2'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.7.Final'

//    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm'
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat
//    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.7.5'

//    compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.32'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.191'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:2.1.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.hashids:hashids:1.0.1'
//    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.12.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.22'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.12.131'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3
    testImplementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.17.102'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/bom
    runtimeOnly 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.102'

    
}
```

Furthermore, when I check I my tomcat 8 logs, this is the error message that I am seeing.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters(CoyoteAdapter.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:786)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:529)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:827)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-9679-ClientPoller-1 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the correct URL?

Comment: For starters stop mixing modules from different version of Spring (Boot) you are mixing 2.2.2 and 2.4.2 which will lead to issues. You don't need `spring-orm` nor `hibernate-core` nor the thymeleaf dependencies all those are provided by the starter dependencies you already include. Also plugins as dependencies?! **How** are you creating the war? I do not hope you use some export function of your IDE but rather Gradle to generate the war file. Finally which tomcat version is on your server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Excuse my obvious mistakes but I am fairly new to this. I shall remove the redundant dependencies and try again. I am generating the war file using the CMD and gradlew bootWar command.

Comment: I have commented out the redundant code in the build file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve that issue. Apparently the problem was that I was using `Tomcat 10`. According to some posts online, `Tomcat 10` does not support **Springboot**. Changing my `Tomcat` version from **10** to **8** solved the problem.